# Can I give a 'web address format' to my local host application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I host a local application on my machine which I provide access on network by normally type `http://computername/app`. Can I change it to a real web address format `www.myapplication.org` for my local hosting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can, by setting up a mapping in your `hosts` [file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29):

```
127.0.0.1 www.myapplication.org
```

Note that, if you've got it running under as a virtual folder, you'll need to still append `/app` or similar to the end.

Comment: i just wanted to know that shouldn,t www.myapplication.org be a registered domain

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro: No, you can just invent any old name and put it in there. You can do it with already-registered names as well. The hosts file is just a "1st-step" place that Windows looks when doing DNS lookups. So it overrides any other sources; so no, it doesn't need to be registered with a domain registrar.

Comment: Thanx, but off the question, i dont think it will be accessible from internet with that domain.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the site to be on the public Internet you will need to complete the following steps:

1) You will need to first purchase and register a domain name.  You can purchase one from GoDaddy, eNom, Dotster, or any other domain registrar.
2) Once you have the domain purchased you will need to create an A DNS record on the provided DNS hosting pointing to your Public IP address.

3) The final step is configuring you web server to recognize the www.myapplication.org or whatever domain you selected.  For IIS look into setting Host Headers and Apache uses something called Virtual Hosts.

If you don't want to go through all of that, the easiest solution is going to be to purchase a hosting account from a web hosting provider.